# Prevent DateRangeField overlap in Django model?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Now that Django supports the [DateRangeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#daterangefield), is there a 'Pythonic' way to prevent records from having overlapping date ranges?

## Hypothetical use case

One hypothetical use case would be a booking system, where you don't want people to book the same resource at the same time.

## Hypothetical example code

```py
class Booking(models.model):
    # The resource to be reserved
    resource = models.ForeignKey('Resource')
    # When to reserve the resource
    date_range = models.DateRangeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('resource', 'date_range',)
```

Comment: Did you eventually get a solution?

Comment: Not yet. This may end up being a feature request for the Django ORM.

Comment: I cross-posted the question to the Django developers list: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/django-developers/9AK7z9iEJCY

Comment: Yap. Would be a nice feature to have.. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know that the answer is old, but now you can just create a constraint in the meta of the model, that will make Postgres handle this

```
from django.contrib.postgres.constraints import ExclusionConstraint
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateTimeRangeField, RangeOperators
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()


class Reservation(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timespan = DateTimeRangeField()
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            ExclusionConstraint(
                name='exclude_overlapping_reservations',
                expressions=[
                    ('timespan', RangeOperators.OVERLAPS),
                    ('room', RangeOperators.EQUAL),
                ],
                condition=Q(cancelled=False),
            ),
        ]
```

[Postgress Coonstraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/constraints/)

Comment: what if there would be multiple rooms -  so the relation from Reservation to Room would be ManyToMany ?

Comment: I think you cant set a constraint for 2 models, you will need to denormalize it somehow.

Comment: For the above answer to work, you have to activate the `btree_gist extension` on PostgreSQL. To this end, add these 2 lines to a migration file: `from django.contrib.postgres.operations import BtreeGistExtension` at the top and 
        `BtreeGistExtension(),` in the `operations`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check this in your model `full_clean` method, which is called automatically during ModelForm validation.  It is NOT called automatically if you directly save the object.. this is a known problem with Django validation that you may be aware of already!  So if you want validation any time the object is saved, you have to also override the model `save` method.

```
class Booking(models.model):

    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Booking, self).full_clean(*args, **kwargs)

        o = Booking.objects.filter(date_range__overlap=self.date_range).exclude(pk=self.pk).first()
        if o:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Date Range overlaps with "%s"' % o)

    # do not need to do this if you are only saving the object via a ModelForm, since the ModelForm calls FullClean.
    def save(self):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Booking, self).save()
```

Comment: this solution does not have consideration for concurrency. Two clients can end up triggering the full_clean methods at the same time, with overlapping range, and both will pass.